# Getting traceback from Python C API

Tags: python, python-c-api

I have a Python C API extension module which occassionally falls over with an uninformative "MemoryError". It's clearly not an error that's catered for by the module's exception handlers. How do I get a more informative error traceback so I can figure out what's gone wrong in the extension module?

Perhaps the question should be, given that I do have the extension module source code, what should I do to get a debuggable version of it with MSVC on MS Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the extension module is claiming to be out of memory -- whether that's true or false, of course, it's impossible to tell without looking at the extension's sources.  Just in case it's true, so that the scarcity of memory might impede a traceback, an old trick is to get some memory earlier and drop it in the error case before reraising it, e.g:

```
reserve = [None] * 10000
try: amodule.somecall()
except MemoryError:
    del reserve
    raise
```

This won't tell you much more than which Python-visible function raised the error (and what Python function called it, etc).  To go beyond that you'll need to compile the extension's C sources for debugging and use some tools such as gdb.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've edited my question. What I actually want to do is debug the module given that I know which python call has triggered that error.